# get the username from user ID in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My models.py is as below,

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = AutoOneToOneField(User, primary_key=False,default=1)
member_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
ph_no = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, default='')
```

My views.py for GET & POST request is below,

```
Class MemberList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)


class MemberCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = members.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
```

Now while creating a Data POST request works fine and I am providing user value as "1 or 2 or 3 etc" depending upon django default User module and these users are already created.

Now when I do GET request , it returns me again only the number 1 or 2 etc of user ID.

Is there any way I can use some method to override and get the username instead of user ID in my GET request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to serializer two field `user_id` and `user_name`. And specify `write_only` and `read_only` arguments to use `user_id` only for POST or PUT and `user_name` for GET requests:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True)
    user_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('user', 'user_name')
```

Comment: It says I have to use queryset argument with following error, "AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`."

Comment: @NaggappanRamukannan you need to add queryset argument to PrimaryKeyRelatedField: `user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True, queryset=User.objects.all())`